# Get outerHTML from a website and put it into a string. I'm lost

Tags: php, outerhtml

There are some (dynamic) websites where the source code is not equal to the outerHTML of the site. For example, the source code of a site of my interest is:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tname-home logo-enable">
                        <span class="tname">
                            <span style="display: none" class="dw-icon ico">&nbsp;
                            </span>
                            <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/team/unics-kazan/rTWGEhHR'); return false;">Unics Kazan</a>
                        </span>
                     </td>
                     <td class="current-result">
                        <span class="scoreboard-divider">-
                        </span>
                     </td>
                     <td class="tname-away logo-enable">
                        <span class="tname"><a href="#" onclick="window.open('/team/maccabi-tel-aviv/nLuro05B'); return false;">Maccabi Tel Aviv</a>
                            <span style="display: none" class="dw-icon ico">&nbsp;</span>
                        </span>
                     </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
```

As you can see this corresponds to a "live score" of a game. In this code, nonetheless, the score doesn't appear. Only the "-" that divides the score of local team and away team.

If we have a look at the outerHTML of the same element, we find this:

```
           <table>           
             <tr>
               <td class="tname-home logo-enable">
                    <span class="tname">
                        <span style="display: none" class="dw-icon ico" title="Advancing to next round">&nbsp;
                        </span>
                        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/team/unics-kazan/rTWGEhHR'); return false;">Unics Kazan</a>
                    </span>
               </td>
               <td class="current-result">
                  <span class="r">
                    <span class="scoreboard">61
                    </span>
                    <span class="scoreboard-divider">-
                    </span>
                    <span class="scoreboard">63
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td class="tname-away logo-enable">
                    <span class="tname"><a href="#" onclick="window.open('/team/maccabi-tel-aviv/nLuro05B'); return false;">Maccabi Tel Aviv</a>
                        <span style="display: none" class="dw-icon ico" title="Advancing to next round">&nbsp;</span>
                     </span>
                </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
```

Note that the code is similar, but not equal, as now, the actual score is visible (61-63 at that moment).

The question is how can I store the outerHTML of the website into a php string, so that I can work with it. The function:

```
file_get_contents("www.website.com")
```

would capture the first code, which has no score on it...

Should you need any other explanation, please let me know. It is very important for me to solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: You need PHP? An AJAX call and send it to PHP is 10 javascript lines.

Comment: At the end I need it in PHP. Could you tell me how to do it in Ajax and then send the variable to php? Thanks

Comment: Are you doing web scraping? It would be easier, if you figured out where that data is actually coming from.

Comment: I don't know where the data come from...